# Remove Inexplicable Black Line In Matplotlib Legend

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, legend

I am using the following code to generate a legend in a separate file. Unfortunately there is a black line in the middle of the legend that has been generated. In the middle of 'permissions modification'. How would i remove this black line ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 10

plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = ['Times New Roman'] + plt.rcParams['font.serif']


"#0C99BA"
"#2f4b7c"
"darkviolet"
"a05195"
"crimson"
"f95d6a"
"ff7c43"
"ffa600"

colors = ["#88D18A", "#0C99BA", "#2f4b7c", "darkviolet", "#a05195", "crimson", "#f95d6a", "#ff7c43", "#ffa600"]
f = lambda m,c: plt.plot([],[],marker=m, color=c, ls="none")[0]
handles = [f("s", colors[i]) for i in range(9)]
#handles = ["red", "red", "wine"]
#labels = ["red", "red", "wine"]
labels = ['Delayed\nExecution', 'File\nOpening', 'Firewall\nModification', 'Permission\nModification', 'Persistence', 'Proxied\nExecution', 'Reconnaissance', 'Registry\nModification', 'Task\nStopping']

legend = plt.legend(handles, labels, loc=3, framealpha=1, frameon=False,ncol=9,handletextpad=0.1,columnspacing=0)

def export_legend(legend, filename="legend.pdf"):
    fig  = legend.figure
    fig.canvas.draw()
    bbox  = legend.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
    fig.savefig(filename, dpi="figure", bbox_inches=bbox)

export_legend(legend)
plt.show()
```

This is the infuriating and inexplicable black line:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you try to save the plot instead of printing it?

Comment: Oh it's the same. If you look at the code it prints to . pdf. The black line output is from both

Comment: Increase the figure width or turn off the axes. What you see is the border of the image - your legend exceeds its  length.

Comment: @Mr.T I suppose you accidentally put your (valid) answer in a comment :-)